# Fedora 31 dnf cannot install packages

Tags: linux, command-line, python, fedora

I am using Fedora 31. When I try to install something with `dnf`, I keep getting errors. For example, when I run `sudo dnf install -y balena-etcher-electron` it says:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 191, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 65, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 98, in _main
    return cli_run(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 122, in cli_run
    ret = resolving(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 166, in resolving
    base.do_transaction(display=displays)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 243, in do_transaction
    tid = super(BaseCli, self).do_transaction(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 882, in do_transaction
    tid = self._run_transaction(cb=cb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 954, in _run_transaction
    tid = self.history.beg(rpmdbv, using_pkgs, [], cmdline)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/db/history.py", line 456, in beg
    int(misc.getloginuid())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/libdnf/transaction.py", line 641, in beginTransaction
    return _transaction.Swdb_beginTransaction(self, dtBegin, rpmdbVersionBegin, cmdline, userId)
RuntimeError: Step: database disk image is malformed in
INSERT INTO   rpm VALUES   (2560, 'balena-etcher-electron', 0, '1.5.76', '1', 'x86_64')
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a broken RPM database. Try `rpm --rebuilddb`.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work.